# How do you organize a Java bean properties name?

Tags: java, javabeans

Refer to [this](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s1-introduction), I wonder how to pick a 'properly' name for Java bean property?

**Way 1:**

```
  public Class People{

   private Integer peopleId;

   private String petName;

   ....
}
```

**Way 2:**

```
public Class People{

   private Integer people_id;

   private String pet_name;

   ....
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well for java, the usual convention is using the lower camel case for variables so I think the right choice would be `peopleId`, and upper camel case for class names.

This is given in the document you have referred. Have a look at [this](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5.1-identifier-names)

Answer (score 3):

proper use of `_` is only when you can't show the start and ending of more-than-one words variable(to show it meaningful name clearly). For example:

`peopleId` - Uppercase `I` indicate that it is a second word

when your variable name is `PEOPLEID` (normally constant variable) use `PEOPLE_ID`

Answer (score 1):

[Java naming conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm) says that you should:

- Use `mixedCase` for methods/variables
- `CamelCase` for classes/interfaces.